# How to navigate to a route in Framework7 + Vue app?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, html-framework-7

How to navigate to a route in Framework7 & VueJs app.

I want to show a slpash screen and navigate to next page after two seconds. Code is pasted below.

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "splash",
        mounted: function() {
            this.$router.load({url: '/about/'});   // error
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                msg : "hello"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Note:** This is app component(Main.vue).

Comment: Try `this.$router.replace('/about')`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna $router is undefined.

Comment: see the last section **Router API** here ( http://framework7.io/vue/navigation-router.html ), that might be the problem

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Tried that too. $f7 also is undefined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally this worked for me.

```
this.$f7.mainView.router.load({url: "/user-settings"})
```

**From Docs**

> Please note, that $route and $router component properties are only available inside of custom page components (and their child components) that you load according to routes. In parent components (like in View, or where you init your Vue app instance) they are not accessible as your app may have few routers (Views) at a time. So in this case use access to initialized View Instance, e.g. $f7.views.main.router or $f7.mainView.router